# Debian's display became fuzzy after suspend [AMD]

Tags: debian, amd-graphics

I installed Debian edu 12 on my DELL Inspiron N5010, it's ok but every time after suspend the display became fuzzy and I had to restart it to fix it. I have KDE on my laptop. What can I do?

The result of `inxi -G`:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Park [Mobility Radeon HD 5430/5450/5470] driver: radeon
    v: kernel
  Device-2: Microdia Sonix 1.3 MP Laptop Integrated Webcam type: USB
    driver: uvcvideo
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.9 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.9
    compositor: kwin_wayland driver: X: loaded: radeon
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa dri: r600 gpu: radeon
    resolution: 1366x768~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.5 Mesa 22.3.6 renderer: AMD CEDAR (DRM 2.50.0 /
    6.1.0-7-amd64 LLVM 15.0.6)
```

Comment: This is not a solution, but in many cases, these kinds of problems are specific to Wayland and switching to Xorg would help. I had (very different) graphics issues which went away when I went back to Xorg, and I have seen many posts about various and varied graphics issues being caused/related to Wayland. Maybe trying?

Comment: @terdon Thank you. Switching from wayland to xorg was the solution.